# How to insert emails containing hyphen/dash in mysql from CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm facing an issue inserting **emails with hyphens/dashes** into mysql. The framework used is **CodeIgniter**. The project is hosted in **GoDaddy** (if this helps). Emails that work are:

> name@domain.com, name@test.domain.com, first.last@domain.com,
> first.last@test.domain.com, name.123@domain.com, first_last@domain.com, first_last@test.domain.com

Email that don't work is, but they work fine in `localhost`:

> first-last@domain.com, first-last@test.domain.com

Here's the form from which the email is inserted:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('index.php?/codes');?>">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Waiver Code</label>
          <input type="text" name="code" id="code" placeholder="Code" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="autogen()" name="saveCode">Generate</button>
</form>
```

The `autogen()` function called from 'javascript':

```
function autogen() {
    var randomstring = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-6);
    var date = new Date().getFullYear();
    randomstring = date+randomstring;
    randomstring = randomstring.toUpperCase();

    var email = $('#email').val();
    var code = $('#code');

    if (!email) {
        alert("Email is required!");
        $('#email').focus();
    } else {
        code.val(randomstring);
        alert("Email: "+email+"\nCode: "+randomstring); 
        
        $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php?/genCode/"+email+"/"+randomstring+"');?>",
          data: ({'email': email, 'code': randomstring}),               
          type: "post",
          success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            location.reload();
            alert('Code added');
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("The following error occured: "+
                        textStatus, errorThrown);
          }
        });
    }
}
```

And finally the insert script from CodeIgniter

```
class GenCode extends CI_Controller {

public function index($email="", $code="")
{
    //$data = array('email' => $this->db->escape($email), 'code' => $code, 'user' => $this->session->userdata('username'));
    //$query = $this->db->insert('codes', $data);
$query = $this->db->query("insert ignore into codes(email, code, user) values('".$this->db->escape($email)."', '".$code."', '".$this->session->userdata('username')."');");
    if ($query == TRUE)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
}
}
```

Things I have tried with no luck:

> $this->db->escape($email)
>
> mysql_real_escape_string($email)

I don't know where I'm going wrong. Or Is it something to do with GoDaddy?

Comment: Why are you passing the email and randomstring in the url and passing them as post values? Seems redundant. Don't use single quotes with $this->db->escape. The escape method inserts quotes for you. You shouldn't have your DB code in a controller, nor should your ajax method be the index method. Make a new method for this ajax call and put the appropriate protection in places so only your site can call your ajax. Your controller method should check for valid ajax, clean the data, and pass it to a model for insert. None of that may solve your problem, but they're fixes you should make first.

Comment: I'm trying to trace your code, it looks like you are calling index twice. You are calling it in your AJAX and calling it when you submit your form. You should be doing one or the other, not both. I think you need some major redesign here.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using PDO. So this example is for PDO:

```
$stmt=$this->db->prepare("insert ignore into codes(email, code, user) ".
   " values(:email, :code, :user)");
$stmt->bindParam(":email",$email);
$stmt->bindParam(":code",$code);
$stmt->bindParam(":user",$user);

$stmt->execute();
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php for more details.

Comment: I'm not using PDO, but MySQL.

Comment: Read the PDO manual please: This is most likely the part of php which you are using to communicate with the MySQL database. If you use it like my answer, it solves all the escape issues for you.

Comment: For the above query to work, I will have to change the dbdriver `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';` to `pdo` and that would require me to change all my queries.

Comment: Yes, but it will prevent the issues you have now, and possibly it also prevents SQL injection.

Comment: @Nobert thanks for your advice. I went through the manual and got some good ideas. But, since I need a quick fix, I'm still looking for a way to resolve this, since it has to go live ASAP. In the long term, I will surely implement PDO.

Answer (score 0):

I had to rework your code quite a bit but I ran this and it worked fine. First the Form. You don't need to submit the form *and* do AJAX, do one or the other. Since simple is always better, I chose to submit the form. Here is the form with a changed controller and method for test purposes. The controller is named email_test and the method is insert email. Also notice (very important) the Javascript call in onclick has an added "return." This is so the form will not submit without a value in the email field.

```
<form method="post" action="email_test/insert_email">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Waiver Code</label>
        <input type="text" name="code" id="code" placeholder="Code" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="return autogen();" name="saveCode">Generate</button>
</form>
```

Next is the Javascript. I reduced this to just checking for an email and generating the code. Also notice the comments.

```
function autogen() {
    var randomstring = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-6);
    var date = new Date().getFullYear();
    randomstring = date + randomstring;
    randomstring = randomstring.toUpperCase();

    var email = $('#email').val();
        /*
         * This checks for a value, but it does not mean its an email.
         * You need a valid email check here too.
         */
    if (!email) {
        alert("Email is required!");
        $('#email').focus();
        /*
         * form will not submit
         */
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#code').val(randomstring);
        console.log("Email: " + email + "\nCode: " + randomstring);
        /*
         * form will submit
         */
        return true;
    }
}
```

Last is the controller and model. For brevity, I skipped the model but you should not do this. Check the comments on this.

```
class Email_test extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

    }

    public function insert_email() {
        /*
         * TODO here...
         * check for ajax
         * check for being sent from yourself
         * clean your input
         * return error and handle if bad input
         */

        // load your model here
        // call your model here which has the following code
        //all this code should be in a model, put here for an example.
        $query = $this->db->query("insert into codes(email, code, user) values(" . $this->db->escape($email) . ", '$code.', '" . $this->session->userdata('username') . "');");
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }

        //handle the return from the model here
    }

}
```